# PHP5 on IIS6 - The specified CGI application misbehaved

Tags: php, iis

PHP v5.2.8

Windows Server 2003  SP2 (IIS 6, I believe, though I can't find a version # anywhere in IIS manager)

The full error is:

```
"CGI Error
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers."
```

I installed the WAMP stack from bitnami.org, and the PHP pages work completely fine when visiting via Apache, which I have running on port 8888.  However, due to network configuration and firewall reasons, I have to get this working on the IIS server on port 80.  There are other websites running on port 80, including a default website that can't be changed.  Unfortunately, I also have to have this running as a virtual directory, such as www.myserver.com/phpapp, instead of as it's own website such as phpapp.myserver.com.  The reason for this is that the firewall, beyond my control, requires new passthrough rules to allow access on a new subdomain.

This same WAMP stack from Bitnami is working fine on another server when the php app runs as it's own "website" in IIS, since I can add a new PHP ISAPI filter - but that tab/option is not available on virtual directories.

I've installed the php "Web Service Extension" in IIS Manager.  I have tried both php-cgi and the php5isapi.dll in the web-service-extensions.  Furthermore, I have tried both of those as the "application extension" under the websites "configuration" mappings.

I've also tried mix/match combinations of the php5isapi.dll and php-cgi.exe for the "web service extensions" and the websites "configuration" extension mappings.

I've tried tweaking a few things in php.ini, (including making sure the doc_root is blank).  However, as I mentioned before, this website works fine when visited via the Apache port.  IIS points to the exact same directory.

What on earth is causing this error?  I've spent quite a bit of time searching online, and it seems this error pops up for a few different reasons.  If one had a PHP app that did a raw write to the response without writing the headers first would cause this error.  Some PHP apps can cause this error when there is a PHP error resulting in some malformed redirect.

My php error logs are missing in action.  In my php.ini I have

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_log = "c:\temp\php.error.log"
```

But there is never a log file in c:\temp.  I also tried escaping the slashes, and tried forward slashes in the path, and the log file never shows up.

Again, I feel compelled to mention that this all works fine via apache, so it doesn't seem like PHP itself is bailing due to some strange configuration (even though I can't find the log file)  Not to mention this is the same php.ini that I use on the other computer where this is working fine via IIS (where the php app is it's own "website" instead of a virtual directory).

I don't know what other info to provide - but I'm at my wits end after battling this off and on for several days.  If I drop an HTML page in, I can visit that just fine via IIS under this virtual directory.  What can be causing this?

The app I'm trying to run is vBulletin.  Not sure that it matters a whole lot other than to give credence to the correctness of the PHP in the app.

Comment: I had same problem with our server. I told reported it sysadmin and he said he changed the timeout and recycle options and it is not happening anymore.

Comment: I mean He changed timeout and recycling settings in IIS...

Answer (score 0):

This should have solve all it, takes care of these issues.

IIS Aid PHP Installer 
http://www.iis-aid.com/iis_aid_php_installer